# How can I move the camera on one axis and simultaneously accelerate with sound (subbass)?

Tags: camera, keyframes, audio, axis

I need your help and couldn't figure it out how I'm able to accelerate the camera movement with the help of sound (bass).

Is it even possible?

Thank's in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange! Just to clarify what you're asking, you want to have the camera moving along an axis and have the sound speed it up and slow it down? Or is the sound going to move it along a different axis? Either way, it sounds like the animation nodes addon would have all the tools you need.

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your quick response. The camera is moving along 1 axis continuously and the subbass of the music track should accelerate the movement in this axis. what is an animation node addon? thank's in advance!

Comment: Animation Nodes is an addon that lets you use nodes to control animations. You could definitely do what you're asking with it, but I'm not very familiar with how it works. Have you tried baking sound to an f-curve in the graph editor? That might be what you're after.